# Python, Tornado: gen.coroutine decorator breaks try-catch in another decorator

Tags: python, exception, tornado, decorator

I have a class with plenty static methods with Tornado coroutine decorator. And I want to add another decorator, to catch exceptions and write them to a file:

```
# my decorator
def lifesaver(func):
    def silenceit(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            # collect info and format it
            res = ' ... '
            # writelog(res)
            print(res)
            return None

    return silenceit
```

However, it doesn't work with `gen.coroutine` decorator:

```
class SomeClass:

    # This doesn't work!
    # I tried to pass decorators in different orders,
    # but got no result.
    @staticmethod
    @lifesaver
    @gen.coroutine
    @lifesaver
    def dosomething1():
        raise Exception("Test error!")


    # My decorator works well
    # if it is used without gen.coroutine.
    @staticmethod
    @gen.coroutine
    def dosomething2():
        SomeClass.dosomething3()

    @staticmethod
    @lifesaver
    def dosomething3():
        raise Exception("Test error!")
```

I understand, that Tornado uses `raise Return(...)` approach which is probably based on *Exceptions*, and maybe it somehow blocks *try-catches* of other decorators... So, how can I used my decorator to handle *Exceptions* with Tornado coroutines?

### The answer

Thanks to Martijn Pieters, I got this code working:

```
def lifesaver(func):
    def silenceit(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (gen.Return, StopIteration):
            raise
        except Exception as ex:
            # collect info and format it
            res = ' ... '
            # writelog(res)
            print(res)

            raise gen.Return(b"")

    return silenceit
```

So, I only needed to specify Tornado `Return`. I tried to add `@gen.coroutine` decorator to `silenceit` function and use `yield` in it, but this leads to `Future` objects of `Future` objects and some other strange unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decorating the output of `gen.coroutine`, because decorators are applied from bottom to top (as they are nested inside one another from top to bottom).

Rather than decorate the coroutine, decorate your function and apply the `gen.coroutine` decorator to that result:

```
@gen.coroutine
@lifesaver
def dosomething1():
    raise Exception("Test error!")
```

Your decorator can't really handle the output that a `@gen.coroutine` decorated function produces. Tornado relies on exceptions to communicate results (because in Python 2, generators can't use `return` to return results). You need to make sure you pass through the exceptions Tornado relies on. You also should re-wrap your wrapper function:

```
from tornado import gen

def lifesaver(func):
    @gen.coroutine
    def silenceit(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (gen.Return, StopIteration):
            raise
        except Exception as ex:
            # collect info and format it
            res = ' ... '
            # writelog(res)
            print(res)
            raise gen.Return(b"")

    return silenceit
```

On exception, an empty `Return()` object is raised; adjust this as needed.

Do yourself a favour and don't use a class just put `staticmethod` functions in there. Just put those functions *at the top level* in the module. Classes are there to combine methods and shared state, not to create a namespace. Use modules to create namespaces instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I mentioned in the Q, I tried different orders of decorators, even `@lifesaver @gen.coroutine @lifesaver`, but this still doesn't work, the request returns 500: Internal Server Error.

Comment: @AivanF.: right, because `gen.coroutine` expects a generator, *always*. I only just read the documentation.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much! And I will try to declare functions rather than static methods `:)`

Comment: @AivanF.: I updated my answer to reflect the realities of the Tornado implementation better.

Comment: I tried to use coroutine decorator and `yield` as you showed, but got many troubles. However, your usage of `gen.Return` was enough to solve the problem. See update of my question.

Comment: @AivanF.: right, so *You may want to consider returning an empty `Return()` value instead of `None` when you silence an exception.* definitely applied here.

Comment: I meant the usual execution flow, not `except Exception as ex:`: `yield`s with `@gen.coroutine` lead to Future of Future instead of just passing results from wrapped function.

Comment: @AivanF.: ah, indeed, as the wrapper *doesn't actually create a generator itself*. Duh.